# PHP mail() screwing up HTML href's

Tags: php, html, email, formatting

I have a mail() function going in a PHP script. It sends HTML just fine - the headers are set up correctly. What IS incorrect, however, is the representation of HREFs - they come out all garbled in Thunderbird.

Here's what's sent:

`<a href='/index.php?page=blahdeblah'>Click</a>`

But what is received is this:

`Click</index.php?page=blahdeblah>`

Notice the link text is before the tag, there is no closing tag (even though one IS included in the original PHP string)

The headers I use are such:

```
$headers = 'From: noreply@' . $url_short . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

(a few PHP variables are used)

Can anyone help with this peculiar issue?

Comment: If nothing else, linking to `/index.php` isn't likely to work. Try an absolute URL. Do the links work in other e-mail clients?

Comment: I find it odd that the quotes are stripped out as well. Try a test with double quotes `<a href="/index.php.php?page=blahdeblah">Click</a>` instead to see if it does the same thing?

Comment: @stealthyninja - I tried it with double quotes to no avail, but thanks :)

Comment: @ceejayoz - Thanks! I was pretty darn stupid to use /index.php - the email client isn't going to know which server to use is it! Thanks muchly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your anchor tag to:

> `<a href="http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=blahdeblah">Click</a>`

- prefix your full domain url to the link
- enclose href attribute in double quotes instead of single (HTML attributes should always be in double quotes, even though single quotes are allowed)

Comment: Any particular reason for "should" being double quotes? It's more commonly used but the spec equally allows either.

Comment: In my experience enclosing html attributes in single quotes does not always work in all browsers/email clients. I do not know the exact reason why this happens but I'm guessing it's because different languages interpret single and double quotes differently. In this case, the single quote could be messing up the PHP mail() function (as pointed out by Resorath) which constructs the final message to be sent in the email.

Comment: this works great - I wasn't using the http:// path. As for the single and double quotes, that was because they're inside a PHP string. I'll change them around to maintain compatibility though.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source of the message and it looks correct, then it's probably something thunderbird is displaying improperly.  If you see the mistake in the source of the email, then maybe there is a problem with your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

ceejayoz mentioned it but: linking to a relative URL isn't going to work as you expected, and might be the cause of the issue. If that doesn't solve it see if it happens in other readers as well.

Comment: See my comment above @ceejayoz. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your whole mail() call? This could just be a problem with bad use of single quotes.

Comment: It wasn't, but thanks. The problem was not using the entire URL (the http://www.domain.com bit), but thanks anyway :)